# Not Found: You need to find "" to view the source for the current call stack frame

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

This alert has turned up a number of times in past editions of VS calling for different files. Interrupting the flow of debugging, it should thus provide a more desirable range of options than the ones presented in the attached graphic.

In this case the file is `strnlen.cpp` required by the function [wcslen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

*Browse and find*- there are currently 182 hits for `strnlen.cpp` on Google, 6 are actual files, and none of them appear to be affiliated with MSFT.

[image: Not Found!]

Would the best option be to log a fault via Visual Studio Feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File was found in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\string

A quick fix while the error is showing would be to create an `enc_temp_folder` subdirectory from the solution folder, and copy the file there, before **F5** debug continuation. The ensuing magic is that both folder & file are automatically deleted after the debug session, without the error returning.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution, you could mark it as answer which can help more people.

Comment: @Fletch Zhou: It's only a partial workaround to an issue which probably stems from adding in `#includes` during project dev- where for some reason references don't stick. Deleting the ipch and pdb files along with their container folders may resolve- although I was hoping someone more experienced could throw new light on the issue. If a better solution is offered, I'll certainly mark that instead. :)