# Debugger for python in Visual Studio 2022 doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

I usually use Visual Studio Community 2022 as my IDE for programming (usually in C++). Once I had some little automation tasks that were way faster and easier to do in python than in C++ so I installed the Python Development workload from the Visual Studio Installer. However I could not run my code from within Visual Studio somehow and had to run it trough the console by hand. Since this was a one time thing I never really tried to fix it.

Now I am back to coding a bit in python and had the same issue again. After some research I found this [.net question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71342354/failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-in-visual-studio-2022) which was similar to my problem and [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75248419/20785822) was in fact for python and helped me solve this. I followed this [msdn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-symbols-for-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python?view=vs-2022) to get it work. I finally could not only code in Visual Studio but also run my code through it.

But now I tried to actually use the debugger (I set some breakpoints) and noticed how execution didn't stop on them. So I tried "Step Into" via F11 and got some error again, similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962685/not-found-you-need-to-find-to-view-the-source-for-the-current-call-stack-fra).

---

**Source Not Found**
*python.c not found*
You need to find python.c to view the source for the current call stack frame

Options:

- Locate pyhton.c manually
- View disassembly

More information
*Source search information*

```
Locating source for 'D:\a\1\s\Programs\python.c'. Checksum: SHA256 {3d e 15 d4 9a 77 5a 8d 50 af a6 b5 ed d4 4 ba d2 d7 9a f7 92 40 5c 76 84 70 7b c5 9 80 63 85}
The file 'D:\a\1\s\Programs\python.c' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'D:\a\1\s\Programs\python.c'...
Looking in the Edit-and-Continue directory 'D:\Programs\WebAutomationTest\enc_temp_folder\'...
The file with the matching checksum was not found in the Edit-and-Continue directory.
Looking in the projects for 'D:\a\1\s\Programs\python.c'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\cvt\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\msclr\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\sys\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\x64\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\arm\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\concrt\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\i386\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\linkopts\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\stl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\vccorlib\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\crt\src\vcruntime\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\atlmfc\include\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\atlmfc\src\mfc'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\atlmfc\src\mfcm'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\atlmfc\src\atl'...
Looking in directory ''...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\crt\src'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\src'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.22000.0\ucrt'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\atlmfc\include'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\winrt'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\Include\um'...
Searching for documents embedded in the symbol file.
An embedded document was not found.
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: D:\a\1\s\Programs\python.c.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'D:\a\1\s\Programs\python.c'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just as I was about to post this question I wanted to try "Step Into" again to see what exactly the behavior was and it suddenly worked. I checked the options/properties I had previously set again and **disabling "Enable native code debugging"** which I enabled according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75248419/20785822) just made it work.